# Kable() in knitr and align-functionality

Tags: knitr, right-align

during a report-building I've noticed a non-standard behavior of the kable()-function. My table contains 23 columns all of which I'd like to have aligned right. Here is the code I use:

```
kable(table[1:8,], align=c(rep('r',23)),digits=2,col.names=c("","","","","","","Group 1","","","","","","","","","","Group 2","","","","",""), padding = 0.15,format='pandoc')
```

No matter whether I use the above code or:

```
kable(table[1:8,], align='r', digits=2,col.names=c("","","","","","","Group 1","","","","","","","","","","Group 2","","","","",""), padding = 0.15,format='pandoc')
```

the following line in the .tex-file arises:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lllllllllllllllllrlllll@{}}
```

which obviously aligns all but one, random column left.

I've provided no example table for this since I suspect it to be a bug. Has anybody had similar experiences? Or maybe even a fix?

Best,

Comment: Using xtable now, has disadvantages, too, but less severe.